# Google Home App does not show any information about sensor state

Tags: google-smart-home

I am trying to add Water Leak Sensor as SENSOR device to Google Smart Home.
I have been using the following guide from Google to develop my app server:

- https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/guides/sensor

In response to Google's `action.devices.SYNC` request I am providing the following response:

```
`{
"requestId": "6894439706274654512",
"payload": {
    "agentUserId": "2225babc-0569-4a34-8b33-e52decacb832",
    "devices": [
        { "id": "11385100264604812424-~-sensor_rf-~--~-",
            "type": "action.devices.types.SENSOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.SensorState"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Кухня",
            "name": {
                "name": "UJIN Aqua-sense"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "notificationSupportedByAgent": true,
            "attributes": {
                "sensorStatesSupported": [
                    {
                        "name": "WaterLeak",
                        "descriptiveCapabilities": {
                            "availableStates": [
                                "leak",
                                "no leak"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
          ]
        }
    }`
```

However, when I view this device in the Google Home App it only presents Device Settings.
I have already checked SYNC json in Validator and no errors were detected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for highlighting the issue. I can reproduce this issue on Android Google Home app. Can you please open a bug in [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) for further debugging and share the same information there including a screenshot. I’m going to follow up with the team and update you through the issue tracker.

Comment: the link you sent seems to be internal, it asks for a google.com email

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.
Opened bug in **Public issue tracker** [BUG 272576521](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/272576521)